# Disable Clientside Routing

Tags: gatsby

I have a static page that is rendered (with additional data) by a Go Application based on the requested path.
This works fine, however React fails to load because Gatsby cannot find the page-data.json based on the given path.

I already tried disabling clientside routing with the '@wardpeet/gatsby-plugin-static-site' plugin, however the problem still exists.

I use the default gatsby template with a modified html.js and without any  or  tags.

I would like to disable clientside routing completely (and remove the app-data.json/page-data.json files) or at least route any request to the same file, so I can deploy the site regardless of the domain path.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand what you mean by "disabling client routing". I have looked at the plugin you mention, but since it didn't help you, maybe the problem is not exactly where you think it is...

Comment: Let's take this all over... Can you please explain what is the relation between your Gatsby site and the Go application? Is the Go program simply serving static files generated previously by Gatsby? Or does the Go program launch the Gatsby process dynamically ("based on the given path"… What do you mean?)?

Comment: Then, you say that would like to remove the app-data.json and page-data.json files. Why? Do you mean that, once on the client, you would like your site to be completely pure HTML/CSS (that is, no React on the client side)? Or are you saying this simply because you get errors related to these files and they appears to be "useless" for your use case?

Comment: Sorry, the go Application is only relevant in regards to the template data that is rendered into the app.

I want a pure HTML/CSS/JS React App, but I dont know the path where it is deployed.. Right now, gatsby tries to load the page/app-data.json and does not find it, which completely disables React

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I properly understand your case, but I gather the following points:

- Once running in the browser, Gatsby can't find your `app-data.json` and `page-data.json` files;
- Your Gatsby site appears to be served from a non-root path (for example `www.example.com/some/more/path/(gatsby site)`).

If that is all there is to it, then what you want is simply to [set a "Path Prefix"](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/path-prefix/) when your gatsby site is built. In short, what you need to do is:

1. In your site's `gatsby-config.js`, export a property named 'pathPrefix' specifying the path from which your site will be served. For example:

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
}
```

2. When you build your site, pass the flag `--prefix-paths` to the `gatsby` command. For example:

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
```

Both steps are required, otherwise, you won't see any difference. Once you will have done this, the client side Gatsby application should be able to correctly fetch all required files.

You do not need to disable client side routing. Client side routing is almost always a good thing, since it makes navigation between pages significantly faster. You should remove that plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work - all paths are prefixed, however the page-data is still not found (the path itself is just prefixed, but if the path would be "/test1/test2", the app-data.json is still expected in that location (+ prefix), and not a fixed path :(

Since the website renders the content of a directory (for example), there is no need for clientside routing, since a redirect is still rendered again by the server. The only reason I want to use react/gatsby for this is to depend on existing React components (for example calculation of container height etc.)